# Partial string match and folder creation using PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, pdf, copy

I have a directory with thousands of files, and I would like to create new directories based on part of the file name, and then sort the partial matching files into those directories.

The files all start with the same prefix, "123-", and then have numbers random and ranging in length, but I do not want whatever is after the numbers. I tried regular expressions, but I am having issues with matching the varying number lengths after the "123-" and skipping everything after the middle number.

```
Example files:
directory\123-4441Zebra.pdf
directory\123-4441Tango.pdf
directory\123-768987Beta.pdf
directory\123-768987Tango.pdf
directory\123-34263XYP.pdf

Example Result:
directory\123-4441\123-4441Zebra.pdf
directory\123-4441\123-4441Tango.pdf
directory\123-768987\123-768987Beta.pdf
directory\123-768987\123-768987Tango.pdf
directory\123-34263\123-34263XYP.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $yourdir="C:\temp\root"
 gci $yourdir -File -Filter 123-*.pdf | %{$newdir=$yourdir + "\" + ($_.Name -replace '(123-\d+).*', '$1'); New-Item -Path $newdir -Force -ItemType Directory; Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Dest $newdir -Force }
```

Comment: Thank you Esperento57! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\> '123-4441Zebra.pdf' -replace '(123-\d+).*', '$1'
123-4441
```

e.g.

```
gci "c:\place\" | mv -Dest { "c:\out\$($_.Name -replace '(123-\d+).*', '$1')\" } -Force -WhatIf
```

---

**Auto-generated PS help links from my codeblock** (if available):

- `gci` is an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)
- `mv` is an alias for [`Move-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113350) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)